# Creating an object in the main method. Printing array values in the object

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# and I have created a small program with 2 classes ( 1 being the class containing the main method).

Instructor class:

```
namespace Exercise4
{
    class Account
    {

        public long accountNo { set; get; }
        public double balance { set; get; }
        public string [] payees { set; get; }
        public long [] payeesAccount { set; get; }

        public Account()
        {
            this.accountNo = 0L;
            this.balance = 0.0;
        }

        public Account(long accountNo,double balance)
        {
            this.accountNo = accountNo;
            this.balance = balance;
        }

        public Account(long accountNo, double balance, string [] payees, long [] payeesAccount)
        {
            this.accountNo = accountNo;
            this.balance = balance;
            this.payees = payees;
            this.payeesAccount = payeesAccount;
        }

        public int DebitAmount(double amount)
        {
            if ((this.balance - amount) <= this.balance)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }

        public int TransferMoney(long payeeAccountNo, double amount)
        {
            if (payeesAccount.Contains(payeeAccountNo))
                return DebitAmount(amount);
            else
                return -1;
        }

        public int TransferMoeny(string nickName,double amount)
        {
            if (payees.Contains(nickName))
                return DebitAmount(amount);
            else
                return -1;
        }

        public string ToString()
        {
            string output = "";

            output += "\nAccount Number: " + this.accountNo;
            output += "\nBalance: " + this.balance;
            output += "\nPayee: " + this.payees;
            output += "\nPayee Account: " + this.payeesAccount;

            return output;
        }


    }
}
```

Main method class:

```
namespace Exercise4
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string [] payee = new [] {"Oli"};
            long[] payeesAccount = new[] {1000L};

            Account reg = new Account(1000,100.00,payee,payeesAccount);

            Console.WriteLine(reg.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to print the value(Payee: Oli, Payee Account: 1000 )of the arrays instead of:

Account Number: 1000
Balance: 100
Payee: System.String[]
Payee Account: System.Int64[]

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: You need to override `ToString`: `public override string ToString()`

Comment: You should use `string.Join` or review your class, if you have only one `payee` and one account, do you realy need `string[]` ?

Comment: And to avoid performance issues, you can replace your string concatenation with a block that uses `StringBuilder` or use string interpolation

Comment: `this.` is almost never needed in C# (i.e. C# is not TypeScript!) as you can change input parameters to avoid name conflicts (and if you adhere to [Microsoft's naming recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) for Properties to be PascalCase and parameters and locals to be camelCase, you should never need to consider it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Join for such purposes

Try to define your method `ToString()` like this:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        string output = "";

        output += "\nAccount Number: " + this.accountNo;
        output += "\nBalance: " + this.balance;
        output += "\nPayee: " + string.Join(",", this.payees);
        output += "\nPayee Account: " + string.Join(",", this.payeesAccount);

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Sure, thanks for the tip! Edited the answer. But that would not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the default method `ToString()` correctly then you can use it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(reg);
```

Without the need to call it esplicitly.

And your overriden method should look like this, with string builder to create dynamic string properly:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var output = new StringBuilder();

    output.Append("\nAccount Number: " + this.accountNo);
    output.Append("\nBalance: " + this.balance);
    output.Append("\nPayee: " + string.Join(", ", this.payees));
    output.Append("\nPayee Account: " + string.Join(", ", this.payeesAccount));

    return output.ToString();
}
```

And even better with `C# 6.0+` using string interpolation:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var output = new StringBuilder();

    output.Append($"Account Number: {accountNo}\n");
    output.Append($"Balance: {balance}\n");
    output.Append($"Payee: {string.Join(", ", payees)}\n");
    output.Append($"Payee Account: {string.Join(", ", payeesAccount)}\n");

    return output.ToString();
}
```

But I can advice you to review your class and decide if you realy need to have `string[]` instead of just `string`, as I can see you have only one payee and their account.

Comment: If I remember right, string interpolation is available since C# 6.0

Comment: @NamiraJV yes, probably